# Find x,y coordinates of line (from binary image) in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, binary, coordinates, pixel

!I am using Matlab with the image processing toolbox, with the purpose of extracting the coordinates of the longest line in an image (I need to reuse these coordinates to transfer to a scanning device).

I managed to get the longest line, using bwmorph, and I obtain the line as a binary 2d array.
Now I tried to get its coordinates using:
[x,y]=find([Longestline])
where Longestline is the 2d array mentioned above.![This is an image of the binary line I obtain] and [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHfoH.png)[this is an image with when I superimpose the original picture and plot(x,y)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S68YP.png)

the problem is that I need to reorder these coordinates to trace a line from adjacent points.
is there a function/method that allows to do that directly from the image?

thanks,

Comment: A straight line, or some sort of complex curve?

Comment: Please post an [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: a complex curve that I also can't easily fit (and have different shapes from image to image). I can't upload an image here unfortunately, but I find the longest line from a skeleton of an image that would look like these ones (top figure) http://fiji.sc/AnalyzeSkeleton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked on a simple test image, whether it will manage with something more complex remains to be seen but I don't see why it wouldn't. Presume here `im` is your original image and `BW` is the binary image with the line you want in it:

1. Find the endpoints of your line with `bwmorph`:

   ```
   [xend, yend] = find(bwmorph(BW,'endpoints'));
   ```

   You can take either end, it doesn't matter.
2. Use `bwtraceboundary` to trace the line from one of those endpoints. 'NW' is the initial search direction. It didn't make much difference in my simple test data, which was just a zigzag.

   ```
   contour = bwtraceboundary(BW, [xend(1), yend(1)],'NW');
   ```
3. Overlay

   ```
   imshow(im)
   plot(contour(:,2),contour(:,1),'r')
   ```

Comment: thanks for your help nkjt, it seems to work really well on all my test images